# train_test_split error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: dataset, data, data-science-model

I am trying to split a dataframe into training and test set and I am getting this error: "train_test_split error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8819, 2795]".

So far, I have tried the following in order to fix it, but nothing works:

- I've checked the shape of every column in my dataframe using a for loop and the .shape function.
- I've tried handling nan values in different ways (filling nans, removing nans, doing nothing to nans)
- I have triple checked the shape of every column and each one is 8819 samples

Normally I know this error happens when X and y are not the same shape, but this does not seem to be the case here. Anyone found another reason this error can be produced?

Comment: I believe that if you included more information on your data, the format of your data and the library you have been using for doing the split, you would help people answer your question more easily.